# Custom window frame - Smooth border?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm drawing a custom border in my application by handling the WM_NCPAINT message in my message handler. The problem is that even after setting the window region, the corners of my app aren't "smooth".

I thought that maybe i could just get the HDC for the screen and interpolate the pixels around the corners to get a translucency effect, but seeing as i would have to re-draw the border constantly when the user moves the window, i don't think it's a valid option.

Does anyone know of a way to simulate translucency or at least smooth out the border near the corners?

Here's what the corners look like:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Xaj9k.png]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [Layered Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx).  This works from Windows 2000 onwards.

If you want Aero Glass effects (Vista onwards) then [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2006/08/10/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-_1320_-Part-3-_1320_-The-Desktop-Window-Manager.aspx) has a nice overview of historical painting techniques and details on using The Desktop Window Manager.

Comment: Thanks, using a layered window worked great. However, now my WM_NCPAINT handler isn't working :(