# How do I set the WINDOWCLASSX hbrBackground alpha channel? (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, alpha, winmain

So, I have a WINDOWCLASSX that I want to set the background to, including the alpha channel, but I only saw an "RGB" macro; no RGBA.

So how do I set alpha on hbrBackground? Here is my code:

```
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;  


wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      
wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;               
wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (GetModuleHandle(0), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYAPP));
wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (GetModuleHandle(0), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MYAPP));
wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wincl.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MAINFRAME);               
wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                     
wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                     

wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
```

On that last line, I want to be able to set alpha.

-Thanks for any help.

Comment: You don't create a transparent window with a transparent brush.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413154/custom-window-frame-smooth-border/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create an alpha channel using a background brush on the window class. You have to apply the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style to the window instead and then use either `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` or `UpdateLayeredWindow()` to set the window's alpha channel.  Read the MSDN documentation for more details:

[Using Layered Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632598.aspx#layered_win)

[Layered Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#layered)

Comment: So I've been working on learning how to use SetLayeredWindowAttributes() and UpdateLayeredWindow() and now I have a window that is semi-transparent-ish (the aero is clearly covering the whole client area) but the inside is white, no matter what color i change the background to. here is my code so far:[link](http://pastebin.com/Wu12uPYD)

Comment: Nevermind, I just figured it out, I made the original brush black again and it works now. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

This just worked out for me:

```
// Set WS_EX_LAYERED on this window 
SetWindowLong(g_mainWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(g_mainWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);

// Make this window 70% alpha
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(g_mainWnd, 0, (255 * 70) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);
```

The `g_mainWnd` variable is the reference to the corresponding window (in my case, a HWND variable).